# hive - how to import csv without providing schema infomation

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

Is it possible to import csv file without providing its header or datatype information in Hive metastore.? because it contains 400 different columns so its very complex to provide.

Size of this file is 500 MB. I am also having stored csv data to HDFS.

(Got hint that Sqoop will help.But How?)

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You can load data into a Hive directly from the db using [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hive) without defining table in Hive by:

```
$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://db.foo.com/corp --table EMPLOYEES \
--hive-import
```

Comment: is it possible without sqoop?